Require Not Working in Test
I am super new to coding so I apologize if this question seems obvious. I have a 30 minute time delay in my contract coded like this
uint creationTime = block.timestamp; 
require((block.timestamp >= creationTime + 30 minutes), "30 minute delay has not passed yet");

Where the creationTime is the start of the transaction and then a 30 minute delay is required before continuing. When I run the transaction using Sepolia testnet the transaction completes with no errors in seconds. So the require 30 minute delay isn't functioning. Is it coded correctly? Will it work in live even though it isn't delaying in test?

You’re assigning creationTime and then comparing it in the next line with the same value by adding 30 minutes, which would always hold true, due to the execution in the same transaction.
So, you need to define creationTime as a state variable and initialize it in the constructor of your contract instead, like:
uint256 creationTime;
constructor() {
    creationTime = block.timestamp; 
}

And, then you can compare it in the desired function using the require statement that you’re using.
